# Probability - Biased Coin Given First Flip Is Heads

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Question:

> An unfair coin is flipped four times. $P(Heads)=0.6$ and $P(Tails)=0.4$. Every flip is independent of every other flip.
> Find the probability of getting exactly $2$ heads and $2$ tails given that the first coin flip was a head.

For some reason I cannot seem to get the right answer. What I have tried:

> $$P(A∩B) = 216/625$$
> The above was obtained using $(nCx) p^x q^{n-x}$
> $$ P(\text {Getting heads on first flip})=P(B) = 0.6 = 3/5$$
> $$ P(A|B) = \frac {P(A∩B)}{P(B)}$$

I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Feeling dumb. Please help

Comment: If someone could also let me know how to format the exponent correctly, I cannot seem to figure out how to add multiple values to q's exponent. Thanks :)

Comment: Use q^{n-x} to get $q^{n-x}$.

Comment: @Cathedral Thank you very much!

Comment: Given the initial $H$, the question comes down to "what's the probability of getting exactly one $H$ out of $3$?" which is a straight binomial computation.

Comment: @lulu I have tried that aswell and it did not work. However please correct me if I am wrong. 3C1 * (3/5) * (2/5)^2 = 72/125. That was my first answer, as they are all independent. Hence I felt the first one should have no influence on the rest of the flips.

Comment: @PleaseSirMayIHaveSomeMore That evaluates to $36/125$, not $72/125$

Comment: @Cathedral I feel dumb now (Forgot (n-x)! in the denominator)

Comment: Does that fix the answer? I notice that a similar mistake seems to have been made in the evaluation of $P(A\cap B)$

Comment: @Cathedral Yea it does. That was the first method I used, I have spent about 40 minutes trying to figure out where I was going wrong. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ be i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb P(X_1=1)=p=1-\mathbb P(X_1=0)$. We compute the conditional probability
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sum_{i=1}^4 X_i=2\mid X_1=1\right)  = \mathbb P\left(\sum_{i=2}^4 X_i=1\right) = 3 p (1-p)^2.
$$
With $p=\frac35$, this reduces to $\frac{36}{125}$.